# How to return to bash script menu after running external progam in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to build a simple menu system for a backup backend on Ubuntu server. Menu would just have a few simple commands; one of them being to start htop. I want to be able to start htop from the bash script menu, look at the stats, close htop and then it should return back to the menu. I should then be able to pick any other option and so forth. I'll link some code

```
#!/bin/bash
HEIGHT=18
CHOICE_HEIGHT=10
WIDTH=78
BACKTITLE="SYSTEM MENU - BACKUP BACKEND"
TITLE="[ M A I N - M E N U ]"
MENU="Tasks:"

OPTIONS=(
Htop           "Monitor server resources        "
AvailableHDDS  "List installed HDDs             "
CheckRAIDZ     "Check RAIDz pool status         "
CreateDataPool "Create new data pool            "
Reboot         "Reboot the System               "
Shutdown       "Shutdown the System             "
Logout/Exit    "Logout the Session              "
Update         "Update & Upgrade & autoRemove   "
Edit           "Edit this script                "
Shell          "Exit to Shell                   "
)

CHOICE=$(whiptail --clear \
--backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
--title "$TITLE" \
--menu "$MENU" \
$HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
"${OPTIONS[@]}" \
2>&1 >/dev/tty)

clear
case $CHOICE in
Htop)
    exec htop
    ;;

AvailableHDDS)
    ls /dev/sd*
    ;;

Shell)
    exit
    ;;
esac
```

When the script runs and I pick the htop option, htop opens fine, when I press F10 to exit htop, I am returned to the console and I have to re-run the script to get back to the original menu.

And for example when I run AvailableHDDS option, it shows me the information, but closes the menu.

Comment: then don't use `exec`

Answer (score 0):

```
exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] file [redirection ...]
    Exec FILE, replacing this shell with the specified program.
```

If you use exec your shell is **replaced** by FILE, so you won't be able to return to that shell.

Then, in your case you don't need `exec`.

Comment: This doesn't make a difference unless you additionally add a loop to go back to the menu

Comment: Yes doesn't make a difference if I don't use exec. I''ll add the loop and see what happens. Thanks